# Почему память не освобождается после удаления ячейки памяти?

Tags: delphi

Прохожу программу по шагам.

Вообщем всю проблему видно на картинке, есть двоичное дерево поиска (оно передается в переменной tr), есть ключ key, функция find возвращает адрес, в котором хранится значение key, в данном случае мне нужно удалить один элемент, с ключом 6 вот такого дерева.

```
  5    
 / \    
4   6
```

Функцией dispose освобождаю память, где хранится элемент с ключом, но почему-то, удалив эту ячейку памяти, оно не удаляется в переменной tr? Вопрос почему?

[image]
[image]

вот сам код:

```
   type
tree = ^trees;
trees = record
            key : Integer;
     left,right : tree;
end;
function find(key:Integer;t:tree):tree;
    var b:tree;
    begin
          if t=nil then
            find:=nil;
          if t^.key=key then
            find:=t;
          if key>t^.key then
            find:=find(key,t^.right);
          if key<t^.key then
            find:=find(key,t^.left);
    end;
    procedure del(key:Integer;var tr:tree);
    var
        d,b:tree;
        key_:Integer;
    begin
        d:=find(key,tr);//запоминаю адресс искомого элемента
        dispose(d);//освобождаю память           
    end;
    begin
        vvod;
        del(6,t);
    end.
```

Comment: Вы определяете то, что переменная не удалилась по тому, что с помощью другого указателя можете прочитать содержимое удаленного объекта?

Comment: ну да, мне нужно удалить элемент с ключом 6 в деревере tr, я запоминаю адресс этой ячейки и записываю ее в переменную d и удаляю этот адресс, ну я так думаюю...

Comment: @Евгений536, как Вы себе представляете **удаление этого адреса** ? Он (адрес) должен исчезнуть из адресного пространства программы ? Что, по вашему, должно происходить при обращении к нему (*после удаления*) ?

Comment: а я больше не буду к нему обращатсья..! мне нужно просто удалить этот адресс.! разве это не возможно?

Comment: я только начал изучать динамическую память, поэтому точно не знаю, подскажите что нужно сделать? в чем ошибка?

Comment: @Евгений536 Вам нужно сделать следующее: **описать вашу текущую задачу в паре предложений на бумаге.** После этого разбить ее на отдельные шаги (составить алгоритм). После этого понять, зачем вам вообще потребовалось очищать какую-либо память и почему это произошло. *А после этого уже можно обсуждать ее здесь)*

Comment: @Евгений536 Просто пока вы не понимаете, зачем делать то или иное действие и зачем вам вообще все это нужно, говорить о чем-то бессмысленно. Здесь вам могут помочь с ответом на конкретный технический вопрос или предложить пути решения **сформулированной проблемы.**

Comment: Почитайте про устройство ЭВМ. Память, адресация, принципы работы ОС.

Ошибки, IMHO, 1) dispose(d) для d = nil (точно не знаю, м.б. в delphi ничего страшного не произойдет). Ну на фоне второй (основной) она меркнет.

2) Представьте, что Вы удаляете узел внутри дерева (не лист). Кто за Вас (компилятор ? Он что, про деревья что-то знает ?) указатели в узлах, связанных с удаляемым узлом менять будет ?  

При удалении листа указатель на него (left или right в "вышерасположеном" узле) тоже надо обnilить.

Comment: не я все остальное представляю как удалять, пока хочу только лист научитсья удалять

Comment: d<>nil кстати, именно в этой задачи

Comment: "Все остальное представляю как удалять" - Вы все поддерево хотите удалить ? Для этого одного dispose() недостаточно. Надо удалять (в правильном порядке) все его узлы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот может кому понадобиться. функции для работы с бинарными(двоичными) деревьями

```
type
tree = ^trees;
trees = record
            key : Integer;
     left,right : tree;
end;
function crNode(key:Integer):tree;
var
    k:tree;
begin
      new(k);
      k^.left:=nil;
      k^.right:=nil;
      k^.key:=key;
      crNode:=k;
end;
function add(key:Integer;t:tree):tree;
var
    d:tree;
    f:boolean;
begin
    if t=nil then t:=crNode(key)
    else
    begin
      d:=t;
      f:=true;
      while f do
      begin
        while key > d^.key do
          if d^.right=nil then
          begin
                d^.right:=crNode(key);
                f:=false;
                break;
          end else d:=d^.right;
        while key < d^.key do
          if d^. left=nil then
          begin
                d^. left:=crNode(key);
                f:=false;
                break;
          end else d:=d^.left;
      end;
    end;
    add:=t;
end;
procedure print(t:tree);
begin
    if t^.left<>nil then
      print(t^.left);
    WriteLn(t^.key);
    if t^.right<>nil then
      print(t^.right);
end;
function find(key:Integer;t:tree):tree;
var
    d:tree;
begin
    d:=t;
    while key<>d^.key do
        if key>d^.key then
          d:=d^.right else
        if key<d^.key then
          d:=d^.left;
    find:=d;
end;
function left_most(t:tree):tree;
var
    d:tree;
begin
      if t^.left<>nil then
      begin
        t:=d;
        while d^.left^.left<>nil do
          d:=d^.left;
        left_most:=d;
      end else left_most:=t;
end;
procedure del(key:Integer;var t:tree);
var
    d,b,parent:tree;
    key_:Integer;
    left:Boolean;
begin
      d:=t;
      while key<>d^.key do
      begin
          while key > d^.key do
            if d^.right=nil then
                exit
            else
            begin
                parent:=d;
                d:=d^.right;
            end;
          while key < d^.key do
            if d^.left=nil then
                exit
            else
            begin
                parent:=d;
                d:=d^.left;
            end;
      end;
      if parent^.left^.key=key then  left:=true else left:=false;
      if (d^.right=nil) and (d^.left=nil) then
      begin
        if left then parent^.left:=nil else parent^.right:=nil;
        dispose(d);
      end else
      if (d^.right=nil) and (d^.left<>nil) then
      begin
          if left then parent^.left:=d^.left else parent^.right:=d^.left;
          dispose(d);
      end else
      if (d^.right<>nil) and (d^.left=nil) then
      begin
          if left then parent^.left:=d^.right else parent^.right:=d^.right;
          dispose(d);
      end else
      begin
          parent:=left_most(d^.right);
          if parent^.left<>nil then
          begin
              d^.key:=parent^.left^.key;
              if parent^.left^.right<>nil then
              begin
                    d:=parent^.left;
                    parent^.left:=parent^.left^.right;
                    dispose(d);
              end else
                    dispose(parent^.left);
          end else
          begin
              d^.key:=parent^.key;
              d^.right:=nil;
              dispose(parent);
          end;
      end;
end;
var
    t,d:tree;
    n:Integer;
procedure vvod;
var
  i,key: Integer;
begin
    Assign(input,'input.txt');
    Reset(input);
    REadln(n);
    for i := 1 to n do
    begin
        REad(key);
        t:=add(key,t);
    end;
    close(inpuT);
end;
begin
    vvod;
    del(27,t);

    Assign(output,'output.txt');
    ReWrite(output);
    print(t);
    close(output);
end.
```

Comment: если у кого будут предложения по усовершенствованию, пишите. буду очень рад! все сделано без рекурсии, за исключением распечатки, что вполне легко поправимо

Comment: что будет если input.txt содержит 4,6,5. ваше дерево будет таким:
<pre>
4
 \
  6
 /
5
</pre>

Comment: да, только что проверил

Answer (score 4):

`New` и `Dispose` используют некоторый глобальный аллокатор памяти в рантайме `Delphi`.

При этом после вызова `Dispose` память для соответствующего элемента **будет помечена как освобожденная** и может быть переиспользована при следующем вызове `New`.

Это не значит, что после вызова `Dispose` соответствующий участок памяти сразу становится невалидным, а лишь означает, что в некоторый последующий момент времени там может оказаться мусор или фрагмент другого выделенного участка памяти.

С точки зрения программиста правило одно - не обращаться по указателю, для которого был вызван `Dispose`. *А что на самом деле происходит в этом участке памяти - это уже дело аллокатора.*

Comment: я всмысле представляю как удалять элементы являющиеся не листьями, а имеющие там одного сына(просто перевести указатель) если двух то поменять его с самым левым из правого дерева.! возникла проблема с одним листьем..! вообще тупо

Comment: @Евгений536

![alt][1]

[1]: http://xmages.net/storage/10/1/0/e/0/upload/370fde98.jpg

Comment: всем спасибо! решил задачу, нужно оказывается не сам указатель очищать, а очищать ссылку на этот указатель у предка, а потом можно и dispose для этого указателя...!

Comment: @Евгений, после публикации Вашей программы мне стало ясно, что терминология у Вас, извиняюсь, дурацкая. Отсюда и непонимание Ваших вопросов. Например, Вы говорите "указатель" очевидно подразумевая узел дерева (см. "очищать ссылку на этот указатель у предка").

В следующий раз попытайтесь понятнее (м.б. доже разными словами) формулировать мысль.

Comment: хорошо! старался как мог! =)